# Copy folder with sub-folders and files from server to S3 using AWS CLI

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I have a folder with bunch of subfolders and files which I am fetching from a server and assigning to a variable. I want to upload this data to S3 bucket with the same folder structure using boto3.
Folder Structure:

```
└── main_folder
   ├── folder
    │   ├── folder
    │   │   ├── folder
    │   │   │   └── a.json
    │   │   ├── folder
    │   │   │   ├── folder
    │   │   │   │   └── b.json
    │   │   │   ├── folder
    │   │   │   │   └── c.json
    │   │   │   └── folder
    │   │   │       └── d.json
    │   │   └── folder
    │   │       └── e.json
    │   ├── folder
    │   │   └── f.json
    │   └── folder
    │       └── i.json
```

```py
        try:
            for dirname in utils['BucketData']:
                cmd = ['aws', 's3', 'sync', dirname, 's3://{}/{}/'.format(input_bucket_name, folder_name)]
                sp = subprocess.run(cmd)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.debug('Command error: {}'.format(e))
```

Variable details:

```
utils['BucketData'] = It is data(mentioned is folder structure) which fetched from server. It is in dict form
dirname = fetching directories and copying to s3 location
input_bucket_name = Bucket name where my folder is located.
folder_name = where I want copy the data.
```

When I run I am getting

```
The user-provided path 'directory name' does not exist.
```

How can I copy the exact data with same folder structure which is assigned to variable in S3?
What is wrong here?

Comment: I'd guess that your problem is that 'directory name' is not a folder in the current working directory of your subprocess (which is presumably your home folder). You should probably use absolute pathnames.

Comment: Can you use `aws s3 sync localdir "s3://yourbucket/dirname"`? Perhaps you need to add the `--region=yourplace`.

Comment: @walter-a, the sync command worked for me... thx!

Answer (score 2):

(First given as a comment, I was not sure it was a solution for the problem.)

You can use

```
aws s3 sync localdir "s3://yourbucket/dirname"
```

Perhaps you need to add the `--region=yourplace`.